# Angular2 - required @Input() param

Tags: javascript, angular

Is there any way to check component inputs in development mode? Smth like `React` propTypes.

I would like to receive warning/error in console if i'm not specifying required input or if provided value has different type.

React behavior could be checked [here](https://jsbin.com/vuneza/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plans for better development time checks of declarative Angular bindings, but because there is currently no construct to make `@Input()` mandatory, there probably aren't any checks planned neither.

You would need to create a feature request.